# Using spring-cloud-aws, when connecting to an RDS instance, where do I specify the database?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, spring-cloud

I'm using [spring-cloud-aws](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws) to connect to an RDS instance (in my case MySQL) on AWS.

The [docs](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html) specify how to make a connection to a specific RDS instance (see below), but they don't explain how to select a specific database within the RDS instance.

```
<jdbc:dataSource id="dataSource"
         db-instance-identifier="myRdsInstance"
         username="${rdsUsername}"
         password="${rdsPassword}">
</jdbc:dataSource>
```

They go on to show how this datasource can be injected into any Spring Bean so you can instantiate a JdbcTemplate... this is all dandy.

I am just failing to see where I can specify/change the database I want to run queries against?

Hoping this is just down to my lack of RDS/Spring Cloud knowledge!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connection to the database is done using the configured database inside the RDS instance. You can connect to the "default" database and then configure an explicit defaultCatalog for MySQL.

The following example (based on your should do the trick

```
<jdbc:dataSource id="dataSource"
         db-instance-identifier="myRdsInstance"
         username="${rdsUsername}"
         password="${rdsPassword}">
   <jdbc:pool-attributes initialSize="1" defaultCatalog="MyDb"
                          testOnBorrow="true" validationQuery="SELECT 1" />
</jdbc:dataSource>
```

We will provide additional support to explicitly configure the DB in [RC1](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/20) or maybe RC2.

Comment: I don't think there is an "id" attribute to <jdbc:data-source> anymore?